Testing if a data path exists in a realtime DB
I need to know the simplest way to test if some data path actually exists in a realtime database, inside a cloud function.
Here something I tried, but I already know it is wrong:
....
admin.initializeApp();
....

exports.listAllUsers = onRequest({cors: [corsAllow]}, (req, res) => {
  ....
  const refStr = "MyDBRoot/SectionTwo/SubSectionOne/"+userRecord.uid;
  // Test code:
  if (admin.database().ref(refStr) === undefined) return;
  ....
});

The existence of the string I build (i.e. refStr) is not the same as the path (refStr) actually existing in the DB and this last point is what I want to test.
Any hint will be more that welcome.
UPDATE:
After some more reading and trying here is the most recent situation.
This is the current state of my source code for the cloud function having an issue:
exports.listSelectedUsers = onRequest({cors: [corsAllow]}, (req, res) => {
  let jsonResult;
  const allUsers = [{}];
  admin.auth().listUsers()
    .then(function(listUsersResult) {
      listUsersResult.users.forEach(function(userRecord) {
        const refStr = "MyDBRoot/SectionTwo/SubSectionOne/"+userRecord.uid;
        const dbRef = admin.database().ref(refStr);
      
        dbRef.once("value", (snapshot) => {
          if (snapshot.exists()) {
            const userData = userRecord.toJSON();
            allUsers.push(userData);
          }
        });
      
      });
    
      jsonResult = {users: allUsers};
      res.status(200).send(jsonResult);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error listing users:", error);
      res.status(500).send(error);
    });
}); /* End of listSelectedUsers */

My problem is that calling the function above (listSelectedUsers) returns an empty answer, though it should not.
Changing the dbRef.once({}) block in the code above to the one below does not solve the problem.
dbRef.once("value", (snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    const userData = userRecord.toJSON();
    allUsers.push(userData);
  }
});

Changing it to the dbRef.get().then({}) block below does not solve the problem any better either.
dbRef.get().then((snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    const userData = userRecord.toJSON();
    allUsers.push(userData);
  }
});

I also tried this, setting async to the containing function:
const snapshot = await dbRef.once("value");
if (snapshot.exists()) {
  const userData = userRecord.toJSON();
  allUsers.push(userData);
}

But again with no success.
On the other hand if I remove the block and leave only these two lines then I get a non empty answer when calling listSelectedUsers.
const userData = userRecord.toJSON();
allUsers.push(userData);

But of course, I get all the users and this is not what I want.

To know if a node exists, you will need to read it
const ref = admin.database().ref(refStr);
ref.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.exists()) ...
})

Or if you're in an async context:
const ref = admin.database().ref(refStr);
const snapshot = await ref.once('value');
if (snapshot.exists()) ...

Depending on the version of the SDK you're using, you may also be able to use get instead of once, but the behavior will be the same.
Also see:

The Firebase documentation on reading data once
how to check if value exists in realtime database firebase
Firebase check if node exist return true or false


Following your indications I tried a number of updates to my code, but without success at this point. Please take a look at the changes I made to the post.

Did you already add a simple console.log("the node exists") inside the if, to see if that shows up when the node exists? If the exists() approach I shared worked (hint: it does), you're probably looking at a new problem, which should be posted as a new question with its own minimal repro. --- Also see What should I do when someone answers my question?

Indeed I see what I expect when using logs as you mention. I have to see where the problem is.
